# How do I convert a MTL file to a OBJ file?

Tags: conversion

I was trying to make a snowman from scratch and when I tried to import the file into blender it showed the xyz axis thing but no object, so I checked the format and it was a .MTL file. I've been trying to find a .MTL to .OBJ converter to fix this problem because .OBJ files have worked in the past. I've found none and was wondering if there was a solution at all.

Comment: Hello and welcome. MTL files contain material data pertaining to a certain OBJ file, while the OBJ file contains the geometry itself. There is no possible conversion between the two because they hold different types of information,  and can't generally be imported alone.